# React Native - Push new item(s) to existing AsyncStorage key?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have a few scenarios where I need to store items in `AsyncStorage` and push new data to their respective keys. One of them is a list of 10 countries stored in `AsyncStorage` like this:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('countries', JSON.stringify(countries));
```

I tried the following, where `country` is the new item I want to push/add to the pre-existing `countries`:

```
AsyncStorage.push('countries', JSON.stringify(country));
```

That didn't work of course...

As stated, I also have a few  scenarios where this functionality is needed. I am trying to find a solution with a reusable react native `AsyncStorage` function to handle the the passed `key` and `data`, and take care of setting the item, or pushing to the item if it exists.

Any idea how to accomplish this functionality efficiently with `AsyncStorage`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var countries = await AsyncStorage.getItem('countries');
AsyncStorage.setItem('countries', countries += JSON.stringify(country));
```

If you tried to grab the 'countries' data after concatting the two strings, you'd obviously get invalid ***json*** like so: `{one json obj}{other json obj}`.

You'd have to parse the JSON and then push it like so:

```
var countries = await AsyncStorage.getItem('countries');
countries = JSON.parse(countries);
countries.push(country);
```

Once we've pushed the latest country we can then save the updated countries object to ***localstorage***.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('countries', JSON.stringify(countries));
```

Obviously you'd add ***try + catch*** blocks when grabbing and retrieving the local storage data (i've just left them out here).

Comment: "countries.push is not a function" I'm getting this error. please help me with this!

Comment: maybe it is better if use **await** before getItem: `var countries = await AsyncStorage.getItem('countries');`

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will add a new item with an exist records,

```
var countries = AsyncStorage.getItem('countries');
AsyncStorage.setItem('countries', countries.concat(country));
```